# How to auto-publish wordpress post to facebook fanpage without a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins

My aim is to make a facebook fanpage for a client who wants his blogposts to automatically show up on his fanpage.

I've already read several posts here in the forums. I've tried several methods to auto-publish wordpress posts to a fanpage in facebook.(notes, ...) The last method I used was making an app and using the "Simple Facebook Connect" plugin for wp.

I got quite confusing with this. I have an app called "myClient" and a fanpage called "myClient". If I publish a blogpost, it automatically shows up on the fanpage but "via myClient". Is there a way on get rid of the facebook app? I don't want to show up the via-sentences because the app is just the connection between wp and fb and has no content at all (the content is on the fanpage)

Hopefully you can help me with that!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to publish something on Facebook, you need a Facebook Application as it's the "*trusted*" connection between your source and Facebook (this is why you have the App Secret and all the authentication/authorization process..etc).

So, ***How to auto-publish wordpress post to facebook fanpage without a facebook app?***

You **can't**! But what you can do is changing the App name to something the Client would agree on (and not being "already taken", of course!).

Comment: Thank you for your help! So what would you think, is it best to make an app for every client or one app for all clients?

Comment: @reiserD: It really depends on the client\s, if they don't have problem try to come up with a generic (service like) name and use the same App for all your clients...if you feel that the clients are nagging about the *via* part, create the same App but with different name (for example: my_client_is_a_b****) for that specific client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notes facility available. It is updated when the RSS address you provide updates.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a way to get rid of the Facebook App - by using third parties automatic Facebook publishing tools like [ZapRobot](http://www.zaprobot.com) - in that way you actually lean on someone else's FB API APP. Note that then you give "manage_pages" permission to the third party. The process should be:

1) Register with ZapRobot - this is a Facebook login, you give them posting rights to your page

2) Define a [job](http://www.zaprobot.com/my_account.html?section=jobs) that posts A LINK (ignore their categories) while the link is pointing to the RECENT wordpress item on your blog

Good luck :-)